# Combine two column result into one column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a quick question that has been bugging me. How can I combine a column in two different table into a single column

Example of table:

```
Employee 
emp_no emp_name
     1 frieza
     2 bulma
     3 goku`

gender 
emp_no emp_gender
     1 unknown
     2 female
     3 male
```

I want to combine column `emp_name` and `emp_gender` into one column like this:
`column emp_name_gender:frieze,bulma,goku,unknown,female,male`

Been trying to format this question so it easy to understand, but it takes my time while im doing my work. so im apologize for this simple format question.

Comment: This is a basic `join` query in SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, can you give an example of the join query. im not so good in sql.

Comment: did you want one row per employee with `name,gende`r - or one row in total with `name, name, ... gender, gender, ... `?

Answer (score 0):

It's a `join`, but with a `group_concat` or two thrown in.

```
select concat(group_concat(emp_name), ',', group_concat(emp_gender))
  from employee
    inner join gender
      on employee.emp_no = gender.emp_no
```

Or if you don't really want it all into a single column and row it would just be

```
select concat(emp_name, ',', emp_gender)
  from employee
    inner join gender
      on employee.emp_no = gender.emp_no
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ae01/4)

Comment: Man, you have the scariest profile picture in SO.

Answer (score 0):

What about a `UNION` :

```
SELECT emp_name AS emp_name_gender  ◄─
  FROM employee
 UNION          ◄█■■
SELECT emp_gender AS emp_name_gender  ◄─
  FROM gender
```

You get exactly the result you ask for :

[image]

There's a comment from [pala_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387356/combine-two-column-result-into-one-column-mysql/70146592#comment48864064_30387356) that worths to answer.